# Run Autocorrelation on dataframe.time including both hours and minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to run `autocorrelation_plot` on a dataframe in python. The format of the data is:

```
2      07:38:30
3      06:32:30
4      07:36:30
5      06:52:30
6      06:47:00
     ...   
273    07:14:30
274    08:47:30
280    08:37:00
281    09:21:30
284    08:10:30
Name: endTime, Length: 199, dtype: object
```

I am able to run it on the hours only by converting with .hour:

```
df_valid.endTime = pd.to_datetime(df_valid.endTime, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').dt.hour
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
autocorrelation_plot(df_valid.endTime, ax=ax)
```

But I want to include the minutes as well for it to be more precise. But when trying to without the .hour conversion first I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'`

Any ideas as to why ?

Comment: What values do you want to be plotted? Is it time in minutes or hours? And do you have the dates?

Comment: the time, including hour and minute. I am guessing that the problem is the plot only takes an int as input

Comment: Yes, that is not possible. You are plotting time (y-axis) against lag order(x-axis). 
In theory that makes no sense too. Autocorrelation is a measure of the linear relationship between lagged and present values. Time cannot be a value if it is also the axis.

Comment: Right, so now I am trying to convert the time stamps into seconds using 

`def time_to_num(time_str):hh, mm , ss = map(int, time_str.split(':'))
    return ss + 60*(mm + 60*hh)

hmm = df_valid.endTime.apply(time_to_num)`

but when I try to I get AttributeError:

 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'split'

Any ideas as to how I can do it ?

Comment: Is your time a `datetime` object or a `str`? You seem to be performing a `str` operation on `datetime` object. Either convert to a `str` or use `datetime` methods. Easily can find answers here.